# My pod gets OOM-killed status, but doesn't get killed. Why?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, containers

I've configured a CronJob with a YAML file (apiVersion: batch/v1beta1) with resource requests and limits, the pod is successfully instantiated and works till its natural end, but when terminates I saw it marked as OOMKilled.

My pod is working with a Docker container, which is started with a bash script that invokes some Java tools (like maven). I tried to setup a MAVEN_OPTS and JAVAOPTS like this:

```
        env:
          - name: JAVA_OPTS
            value: "-Xms256M -Xmx1280M"
          - name: MAVEN_OPTS
            value: "-Xms256M -Xmx1280M"
```

That are values lower than the ones of the configured limit in the YAML.

I'd expected that the pod stops in complete status as the last echo of my ENTRY_POINT bash script is shown in the log of the pod but I get the OOMKilled.

Comment: seems like the program got oom-killed by the container os before they hit k8s resource limit, the conainer terminated itself so k8s considered it as completed

Answer (score 4):

When Containers have resource requests specified, the scheduler can make better decisions about which nodes to place Pods on. But keep in mind: Compute Resources (CPU/Memory) are configured for Containers, not for Pods.

If a Pod container is OOM killed, [the Pod is not evicted](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#node-oom-behavior). The underlying container is restarted by the `kubelet` based on its [`RestartPolicy`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#restart-policy).

Your container [being terminated](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#my-container-is-terminated) by OOMKill does not imply the pod to become in a `Completed/Error` status (unless you're using the `RestartPolicy: Never`).

If you do a `kubectl describe` on your pod, the container will be in `Running` state, but you can find the last restart cause in `Last State`. Also, you can check how many times it was restarted:

```
State:          Running
  Started:      Wed, 27 Feb 2019 10:29:09 +0000
Last State:     Terminated
  Reason:       OOMKilled
  Exit Code:    137
  Started:      Wed, 27 Feb 2019 06:27:39 +0000
  Finished:     Wed, 27 Feb 2019 10:29:08 +0000
Restart Count:  5
```

Comment: I've written pod but i was talking about container yes. Anyway my container was non restarted neither killed, describiing it has 0 restars count and the STDOUT of the container doesn't suggests any kill

My restart policy is: restartPolicy: OnFailure